# What does : mean in python

Tags: python

What does : mean in python? I'm learning how to program in python and the tutorial i'm using
doesn't explain what : does. I can't find what : does on the internet either. Please answer :D

Comment: `:` is part of a larger statement; like `try:` or `if <condition>:`, or in the slicing syntax `sequence[start:stop]`. It is not something that stands alone.

Comment: It introduces a new code block underneath it. It's mostly syntactic, however, for readability.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please show an example of where you are using `:` such that its meaning is unclear.

Comment: @Keith: not just a new code block; there are more places a colon is used. Dictionary literals, slicing notation, lambda expressions all use colons too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In object indices (e.g. `some_list[4:-1]`), this is called *slice notation*. You use it to access parts of a list/object instead of single items. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) for more information.

On other statements, it is required by [the syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html) to introduce a new code block, like on `try:` or `if something:`